# How are these two Guids different?

Tags: c#, linq, guid

I have a odd error. I'm pairing up data with guids to later indentify them and change the original.

I was able to recreate the really complex problem into a simpler one that I can ask here, hence why I'm using strings as data. Consider this as an example:

```
  List<string> testList = new List<string>(new[] { "haha", "wit" });
  var list1 = testList.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<Guid, string>(Guid.NewGuid(), x));
  var list2 = list1.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<Guid, string>(x.Key, x.Value));
  Guid xGuid = list1.First().Key;
  Guid yGuid = list2.First().Key;

  System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(xGuid.ToString());
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(yGuid.ToString());
  System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

Just take the piece of code and run it. In the output window of visual studio you should see two guids, just like these two:

```
35ac8c6a-928c-46a9-a614-9d35c2427219
d2175358-85f8-4467-be02-34932f2f4804
```

Note: *They are not the same*

Now my question is:

How, or *why* are they even different?

I create one guid here:

```
var list1 = testList.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<Guid, string>(Guid.NewGuid(), x));
```

And then it is only being copied:

```
var list2 = list1.Select(x => new KeyValuePair<Guid, string>(x.Key, x.Value));
```

So why are these different?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Delayed execution.  Put a `ToList` at the end of the `list1` assignment and it will be the same value.  Basically `Guid.NewGuid` is getting called twice when you call `First` on `list1` and then on `list2`.

Comment: You're creating two LINQ queries - that each time you access them re-run the code within the `Select` lambda.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever oh - seems like lazy-evaluation rekt me once again :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have encountered the magic of Linq.  Try this:

```
var list1 = (your code).ToList()
var list2 = (your code).ToList()
```

and see if you don't get identical values.  Linq's Select is executed each time in your code, resulting in a new guid each time.  The actual terms are Projection and Realization, I think.

Comment: I think that solved it yes. Is that because parts of linq are implemented with lazy execuation (executed when you request the data)?

Comment: @Mafii Yes, that's exactly what's happening.

Comment: To explain, In the original code, `List1` wasn't a list, but an IEnumerable object, which would generate a new list each time it's run.

Comment: This is a terrible answer - the presented code doesn't match the issue and the explanation isn't very clear. It should be improved.

Comment: @Enigmativity while I agree it's not a perfect answer, it solves the problem, just on a more abstract level. It's very clear what's the solution to my problem, but it could be more clear on when to use the ToList() and when not.

Comment: The answer shows what to add without it getting lost in the long statement.  What is important is the Delta.